# Is there a standard way to statically initialize flexible array members in C?

Tags: c, flexible-array-member

I need a statically created data structure in memory comprised of a table of string vectors, effectively:

```
typedef struct {
    char *argv[];
} Entry;

const Entry Table[] = {
    {"a"},
    {"a", "b", "c"}
};
```

But trying to compile this results in `error: initialization of flexible array member in a nested context`

Apparently this is possible in GCC, according [GCC Manual: 6.18 Arrays of Length Zero](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html).
This may be possible following C 2018 6.7.2.1 18, although in regard to that I read elsewhere

> There cannot be an array of structures that contain a flexible array member.

Is there a standard way to achieve this behavior? If not, is there a *preferred* way?

Comment: No, it's not possible. The memory for a struct containing a flexible array member has to be allocated dynamically with `malloc()`.

Comment: Why do you need a FAM? Why not use `char **argv`?

Comment: Additionally, a structure containing a FAM must have at least one named member other than the FAM.

Comment: `struct { char *argv[]; }` is not a proper structure definition in standard C. C 2018 6.7.2.1 says “As a special case, the last member of a structure with more than one named member may have an incomplete array type; this is called a *flexible array member*.” That declaration has only one named member, not more than one. To properly declare a structure with a flexible array number, there must be an earlier ordinary named member.

Comment: You also cannot have a useful array of structs with flexible array members.

Comment: Note that in Standard C (which is different from GNU C), you must have at least one other element before the FAM in a structure.  [§6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers ¶18](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p18): _As a special case, the last element of a structure with more than one named member may have an incomplete array type; this is called a flexible array member._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it with a flexible array member.

Instead, you can use `char **argv` and initialize it using compound literals.

```
typedef struct {
    char **argv;
} Entry;

const Entry table[] = {
    { (char *[]) { "a", NULL } },
    { (char *[]) { "a", "b", "c", NULL } }
};
```

I added `NULL` to each of the arrays so the application can tell their lengths (the real `argv` has this as well).

Comment: Drop the parentheses around `char *` in the compound literals: `(char *[]) { "a", NULL }`.

Comment: You don't need to use `Entry` literals.  Just dropping the `(Entry)` bits yields an ordinary initializer that works for me.  With `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20719966/initializer-element-is-not-constant-using-designated-initializer-on-static-str

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, I'll read that. Dropping `(Entry)` made [3 compilers happy](https://godbolt.org/z/efoYrq5cz) in C2x mode though.

Answer (score 0):

You do not store the count of elements of argv. How would you know that the first one has 1 element, and the second one has 3? You have to store that, for example, in another array member.

You can define a structure that has the proper exact same static memory layout as the array of structures with flexible array members that you want to have. Then you can then alias the structure with a pointer to `Entry`, and use that as an array of entries. Following example does that:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdalign.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    unsigned len;
    char *argv[];
} Entry;

// sane iterating
static_assert(alignof(Entry) == alignof(char *), "");

typedef struct {
    unsigned len;
    char *argv[1];
} Entry_1;
static_assert(alignof(Entry_1) == alignof(Entry), "");
static_assert(sizeof(Entry_1) == sizeof(Entry) + 1 * sizeof(char *), "");

typedef struct {
    unsigned len;
    char *argv[3];
} Entry_3;
static_assert(alignof(Entry_3) == alignof(Entry), "");
static_assert(sizeof(Entry_3) == sizeof(Entry) + 3 * sizeof(char *), "");

typedef struct {
    Entry_1 e1;
    Entry_3 e3;
} Entry_init_1_3;
static_assert(offsetof(Entry_init_1_3, e3) == sizeof(Entry_1), "");

const Entry_init_1_3 entry_init_1_3 = {
    { 1, { "a", } },
    { 3, { "b", "c", "d", } },
};

const Entry *const table = (const void *)&entry_init_1_3;
//                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ I hope I know what I am doing.
const Entry *const table_end = (const Entry*)((const char*)table + sizeof(entry_init_1_3));

const Entry *table_next(const Entry *it) {
    return (const Entry *)(
        (const char *)it + sizeof(Entry) + it->len * sizeof(char *)
    );
}

int main() {
    unsigned entry_idx = 0;
    for (const Entry *it = table;
            it != table_end;
            it = table_next(it), ++entry_idx
    ) {
        for (unsigned x = 0; x < it->len; ++x) {
            fprintf(stderr, "table[%d].argv[%d] = %s\n",
                entry_idx,
                x,
                it->argv[x]
            );
       }
    }
}
```

Code outputs:

```
table[0].argv[0] = a
table[1].argv[0] = b
table[1].argv[1] = c
table[1].argv[2] = d
```

Most notable [inotify()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) Linux system call returns an array of flexible array members.

> Is there a standard way to statically initialize flexible array members in C?

No.

> If not, is there a preferred way?

Don't use flexible array members. Use pointers, as presented in the other answer.